# Customization to bring back old tab context menu in Notepad++ not working?

Tags: notepad++, context-menu, tabs, version, workflow

The new context menu in Notepad++ is inconvenient because I have to go to a submenu to do actions like clone document to other view.

To fix this, I basically just followed the instructions [here](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/23956/bringing-back-the-old-pre-8-4-6-filetab-right-click-context-menu/4). Downloaded [the file](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/files/10128562/tabContextMenu_8.4.5_and_earlier.TXT), renamed it to tabContextMenu.xml, put it in *C:\Program Files\Notepad++*, even restarted my computer, but the same new context menu is there.

What gives?

Comment: What npp version are you using?

Comment: How about create a shortcut that clones the current document?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already did all the things needed, just that you are probably just one step away. Try putting the tabContextMenu.xml in %APPDATA%/Notepad++/, it should work.

I was also not a fan of this sub menus so I tried someways but in the end, I had to put this file under appdata directory.

Good luck!